# Can't resolve 'fs' when using Instascan in Next js project

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to use [Instascan](https://github.com/schmich/instascan) in my `Next JS` project, but I'm getting an error `Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/node_modules/instascan/src'`. I'm assuming this has to do with SSR. I tried to set the webpack config using the `next.config.js` file based on [this comment](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/447#issuecomment-285598881):

```js
module.exports = {
    webpack: (config) => {
        return Object.assign({}, config, {
            node: {
                fs: 'empty'
            }
        })
    },
};
```

But that doesn't seem to work either, I assume because that webpack config is for the client side? I've read that people also [bundle their server using webpack](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/447#issuecomment-488284990), not 100% sure if that's the case with `next`, also not sure if that would fix anything. Anyone who can guide me into some sort of solution here? Not really sure how I can advance anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I honestly don't see the difference, but using a spread operator seems to fix it?

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config) => {
    return {
      ...config,
      node: {
        fs:
          'empty'
        }
      }
   }
};
```

Now I'm getting an `Instascan`-specific issue, so this is closed.